# Can i create a "local" jobs (or triggers) when the scheduler is configured in cluster mode?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I tested successfully for schedulers clustered with jdbcjobstore.

But i would like to create some jobs that could be specified for some of schedulers. I thought that by setting "isVolatile" to "true" but triggers (with isVolatile=true) still be saved in database.

Any helps could be appreciated !

PS: i'm using Quartz 1.8

Answer (score 1):

Volatile jobs are non-volatile in a clustered environment. In that case I would suggest to use a RAMJobStore on your scheduler.

Normally you should have in your logs :

```
note: volatile triggers are effectively non-volatile in a clustered environment.
```

Comment: ebtokyo, Thanks for your response but i would like to use scheduler clustering for several physical machines so i have to use jdbcjobstore ...

Comment: You can create many scheduler per JMV. you can have have one JDBCJobStore for clustered jobs and one RAMJobStore for local jobs.

Comment: Yes,effectively i can do that. But how about performance consideration in this case ?

Comment: It should not have a hudge impact but it depends your requirements, Note that a JDBCJobStore is less performant than a RAMJobStore.